# MySql Update and Replace a Table Field relative to other field

Tags: mysql

I want to replace a table field based on other table field condition,

How it now

```
Table : question 
---------------------------
Category  | Subcat |
--------------------------
11           0
11           0
11           0
11           0
11           0
12           1
12           1
12           1
12           1
----------------------
```

I want to replace 0 with 5 where main category is 11

I have tried below code

```
UPDATE `question` SET `subcat` = REPLACE(`subcat`, '0', '5')
```

This replace all 0 present in any main category not in based on particular

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need  a proper where condition for filter the rows  you really need  to change

```
UPDATE question 
SET subcat = 5 
where category =11 
and subcat  = 0
```